# How to catch warnings and verbose messages from console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I try to use chrome DevTools Protocol. I use Log and Runtime Domain for it.

```
// tabId is current tab id
chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId }, '1.3', onDebuggerAttach.bind(null, tabId));

//enable Log and Runtime domains
const onDebuggerAttach = async tabId => {
  await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId}, 'Log.enable');
  await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId}, 'Runtime.enable');
  chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onDebugEvent);
};

//get console messages
const onDebugEvent = (debuggeeId = {}, message, params = {}) => {
  switch (message) {
    case 'Log.entryAdded':
    case 'Runtime.consoleAPICalled':
      handleConsoleMessage(params);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

The problem is that I don`t get any verbose messages and only get some warnings messages not all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try [Log.startViolationsReport](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Log/#method-startViolationsReport).

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried it and get an empty object as a result when I use Log.stopViolationsReport

Comment: I don't know. Try finding what's different about the omitted messages.